# Rashba Spin Orbit Coupling In graphene

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, graphene

I'm trying to understand the Rashba spin orbit coupling induced in graphene by proximity effect with Au(or any other metal)adatoms. It is not really clear for me. I know that the Rashba spin orbit coupling is obtained by the presence of an Electric field which induced to break the inversion symmetry of graphene(A and B sublattices are not equivalent). But how Au can induce this effect? Where is the electric field in this situation? What happens at the interface? Thank you in advance for your help :)